# I wanto to show that if $f(x)\cap f(y)\neq\emptyset$ then $f(x)=f(y)$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $\Sigma$ a $\sigma$-álgebra over $X$.

Suppose that $\Sigma$ is countable. We define $f:X\to\Sigma$ by $f(x)=\bigcap\{A\in\Sigma:x\in A\}$. I want to show that if $f(x)\cap f(y)\neq\emptyset$ then $f(x)=f(y)$.

I tried this:

Suppose $z\in f(x)\cap f(y)$, I think it would be $f(z)=f(x)=f(y)$.

If $z\in f(x)$, I already proved that $f(z)\subseteq f(x)$.

(Actually, it's easy to see that $x_1\in f(x_2)$ implies $f(x_1)\subseteq f(x_2)$)

So, finally I want to prove that $x\in f(z)$ and would be done. How can I prove this?

Thanks.

Comment: What's problematic to me is that we don't know the nature of $\Sigma$. I think I can imagine particular definitions of $\Sigma$ for which the proposition is untrue...

Comment: What happens when $\{A \in\Sigma: x \in A\} = \emptyset$? There is not intersection $\bigcap$ defined over $\emptyset$, is there?

Comment: @Newb I edited it. Do you think this is true now?

Comment: @Surtan unfortunately I don't know anything about $\sigma$-algebras, so I can't comment. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x\notin f(z)$. Then there is a member $A$ of $\Sigma$ which contains $z$, but not $x$. Then $A^c$  is a member of $\Sigma$ which contains $x$, but not $z$. This contradicts the fact that $z$ belongs to every member of $\Sigma$ which contains $x$ (by virtue of $z \in f(x)$).

Comment: Ohhh, it was so simple! Very very thank you @kobe

Comment: @Surtan no problem! :-)